# Electron (chromium) disable web security

Tags: chromium, electron

Is there a way to disable web security on Electron (chromium)?
Via JavaScript or something?

Answer (score 37):

Found it:

```
new BrowserWindow({webPreferences: {webSecurity: false}});
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 6):

In electron's [Documentation](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/browser-window/) for BrowserWindow you can use the object 'webPreferences' that comes along with a couple options, 'webSecurity' being one of them. What worked for me to disable web security was the following:

```
const win = new BrowserWindow({
  webPreferences: { webSecurity: false }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    height: 563,
    useContentSize: true,
    width: 1000,
    webPreferences: { webSecurity: false }
  })
```

```
import { app, BrowserWindow } from 'electron'

  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    height: 563,
    useContentSize: true,
    width: 1000,
    webPreferences: { webSecurity: false }
  })
```

This is the solution, and it works for me.

Comment: Welcome to SO. An explanation of how your code solves the problem makes your answer more useful to a greater number of users.

Answer (score 3):

```
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({

    'web-preferences': {'web-security': false},
    width: 1800,
    height: 1600,

});
```

web preferences part fixed the issue for me.if it didn't work try

```
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('disable-web-security');

mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    'node-integration': 'iframe',
    'web-preferences': {'web-security': false},
    width: 1800,
    height: 1600,
});
```