# Cannot establish connection with socket.io - Angular 7

Tags: angular

I trying to establish connection for the first time with web sockets inside my angular app.
But its not working and its replacing the url path

My socket service

```
 public initSocket(): void {
        this.socket = socketIo('http://11.11.11.111/demo-api/status/');
    }
```

Error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://11.11.11.111/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Meccctccu' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Comment: Are you using node as a backend ?

Comment: @Sachin Shah No

Comment: I'll recommend to use HTML5 - WebSockets instead of socket.io. I was also facing lots of issues while using socket.io in my project then I found two very useful link ref1# https://medium.com/@lwojciechowski/websockets-with-angular2-and-rxjs-8b6c5be02fac, ref2# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43328451/rxjs-observable-with-websocket
HTML5 - WebSockets working like a charm in my project

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable cors in your backend.

You should [read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) about what cors mean and enable it in the backend

Comment: Its got nothing to do with CORS

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing is quite self-explanatory. You can't connect to another domain via ajax or using web socket if the current domain you are accessing it from does not exist in the allowed origins (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header).

There is a very good explanation of what CORS is on the [Mozilla Developer website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

To fix this you will need to add a few headers into the backend you are trying to access which are:

- [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin): `*` (which means allow `ANY` origin and is not a good idea in production!)
- [Access-Control-Allow-Methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Methods): `GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS, any other you might need`
- [Access-Control-Allow-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers): `Accepts, Authorization, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method, DNT, Keep-Alive, User-Agent, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, Cache-Control, Content-Type, Content-Range,Range`

If you are running your Angular app as an Electron one (for example), you can disable CORS checks: [Electron (chromium) disable web security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35852684/electron-chromium-disable-web-security)

> const win = new BrowserWindow({
>     webPreferences: { webSecurity: false }
>   });